# Selenium won't click on all buttons only a few

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click the buttons on the left-panel of the web-page I'm trying to scrape. However, by using `Selenium`, it seems to only click only on a few of these buttons. I have added a `time.sleep` between each click which did not make a difference.

I just get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@class='toggle-bottom-filter'])[7]"}
```

I have double checked that path and it does exist on the website. So I'm not certain as to why it's undetectable, any ideas?

Here's my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.theparking.eu/#!/used-cars/")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,15)     
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bloc-filter")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='sd-cmp-25TOo'] span[class='sd-cmp-16t61 sd-cmp-2JYyd sd-cmp-3cRQ2']"))).click()

#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Electric car drivers will soon no longer be able to charge their cars here.']")))

stuff = []
for more in range(1, 9):
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//div[@class='toggle-bottom-filter'])[{more}]").click()
    data = driver.page_source
    # ... parse with beautifulsoup
```

Comment: I couldn't find element matching this locator there `div[class='sd-cmp-25TOo'] span[class='sd-cmp-16t61 sd-cmp-2JYyd sd-cmp-3cRQ2']`. What element are you clicking there?

Comment: @Prophet It's a pop-up for cookies so the locator clicks on 'accept all'

Answer (score 0):

Not all the 9 elements you are trying to click are initially visible, you first will have to scroll the element into the view and only after that click them.
I see there are 11 elements matching `//div[@class='toggle-bottom-filter']` locator there so possibly you should change the `for` loop to `for more in range(1, 12):`
I think the following code should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.theparking.eu/#!/used-cars/")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,15)     
actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bloc-filter")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='sd-cmp-25TOo'] span[class='sd-cmp-16t61 sd-cmp-2JYyd sd-cmp-3cRQ2']"))).click()

#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Electric car drivers will soon no longer be able to charge their cars here.']")))

stuff = []
for more in range(1, 12):
    time.sleep(2)
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//div[@class='toggle-bottom-filter'])[{more}]")
    actions.move_to_element(button).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    data = driver.page_source
    # ... parse with beautifulsoup
```

Comment: This definitely works slightly better as it clicks one or two more however, I still have some un-clicked. I have maximised the window but some still aren't clicked like ```model``` and ```doors```. I'm not sure what ActionChains does, but I'll look into it! Perhaps scrolling down may help figure it out?

Comment: This is what I'm doing here. `actions.move_to_element(button).perform()` scrolls to the element.

Comment: Also, I see there are 11 elements matching `//div[@class='toggle-bottom-filter']` locator there so possibly you should change the for loop to `for more in range(1, 12):`

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have tried just this and also integrated a `try` and `except` to skip those without the button. However, it seems selenium skips some of the buttons for whatever reason. This is turning out rather tricky!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't actually debug this code, but as I see it should work. Please let me know when you finally find the working solution. I hope my answer should be at least partially useful here.